# Python json.load() returning error unusual JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am developing a python script, and it must read a JSON file.

Here is the code i have:

```py
import json
f = open('data.json', 'r')
a = json.load(f)
```

for some reason, I am encountering the following error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
     return loads(fp.read(),   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
     return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 22 column 1 (char 796)
```

I have tried to investigate this issue on the internet, but could not find anything that may be helpful.

Comment: This is probably problem with JSON formatting. Can you paste the JSON? Or at least lines around 22.

Comment: Can you share a sample json?

Answer (score 0):

Always validate your JSON with jq.

Install jq

$ jq < file.json

Perhaps it is some quoting or unicode issue.

Then re run your python code.

Answer (score 0):

The file is in binary form, you can try reading in `utf-8`:

```
with open('data.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    a = json.load(f)
```

`with` handles the correct opening and closing of the file, the `encoding` argument to `open` ensures the file is read using the correct encoding.